# Segmentation fault while using ferror() in a simple program. Why?

Tags: c, gdb

Why is the following code giving segmentation fault?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("text","r");
    if (file == NULL) printf("Error READING FILE");
    if (ferror(file)) printf("error reading file");    //line 9
    return 0;
}
```

Doing backtrace in gdb gives:-

```
> #0  0x00007ffff7ad9d30 in ferror () from /lib/libc.so.6
> #1  0x00000000004005fa in main () at test.c:9
```

Comment: why are you continuing execution after you find that file is `NULL`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `fopen` returns NULL, then the file isn't open; you're passing `NULL` in to `ferror`, which is invalid. You don't have an open file to pass in; that's what `NULL` means, that it couldn't give you a file pointer. `ferror` is for getting errors related to reading and writing the file, once it has actually been opened and you have the file to work with.

If `fopen` fails, and you want to get more information about why, you need to check the [`errno` global variable](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-errnovariable/), defined in `errno.h`.

```
#include <errno.h>

// ...snip...

if (file == NULL) 
  printf("Error READING FILE: %s\n", strerror(errno));
```

This example shows how to fetch a string describing the error; you could also compare the value in `errno` against one of the possible values it could have, and do something different depending on what the error is. See the [`fopen` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen), or the [POSIX spec](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fopen.html), for a list of possible errors to compare against. Here's how you could check against various possible errors:

```
if (file == NULL) {
  int error = errno;  // copy it so other calls like printf don't modify it
  printf("Error READING FILE: %s\n", strerror(error));
  switch (error) {
  case EACCESS:
    // access was denied
    break;
  case ENOENT:
    // the file or one of its ancestors doesn't exist
    break;
    // etc...
  }
}
```

(this is an expansion of something I originally wrote in a comment on another answer)

Comment: +1, nice answer. Note that the C standard doesn't require `fopen` to set `errno` (POSIX does).  You should set `errno` to 0 before calling `fopen()`, "just in case".  Also, `errno` may or may not be a global variable: it is a modifiable lvalue, which may result from a function call if the library implements it like that.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Alok. I thought of mentioning that `errno` is not actually a global, but I think that would be more confusing than enlightening. I was not aware that C doesn't require `fopen` to set `errno`; most C code I write is on Linux, Mac OS X, or the BSDs, so I tend to pay more attention to the man pages, and POSIX, than the C standard. It's good to know that that assumption isn't necessarily portable.

Comment: Yeah - I see it as a quality of implementation issue too - so it would be hard to find a good library that doesn't set `errno`, particularly because POSIX requires it.

Answer (score 7):

file is NULL.  You're not seeing the first printf because the program crashes before stdout is flushed.

Comment: If i add:- 
fflush(stdout) 
before line 9, i get the output.
But, just for information I want to know, when is stdout flushed in programs?

Comment: When you print a newline character*, or when the buffer is full, or when the program ends.  (*): By default, `stdout` is line-buffered on most systems.  You should also print error messages on `stderr`: usually it's unbuffered (but more importantly, error messages should go to `stderr`, not `stdout`).

Comment: @Alok
Thanx for the reply.. Exactly what I asked.

Answer (score 3):

If file is equal to NULL on line 9, then the Seg Fault will occur during the `ferror()` call.

If there the file is NULL (as determined on line 8), then you shouldn't perform line 9.

Your line 8 code should be changed as such:

```
if (file == NULL)
{
    printf("Error READING FILE");
    return 1;
}
```

NB: i could be very wrong about this, it's been a while since i've done C/C++

Comment: Or change line 9 to `else if ...`.

Comment: I thought ferror() can be used for checking if the file could be opened successfully. But, its used after the file is opened and checking further error, if any..
Am i right?

Comment: ferror() checks the stream to see if  the error indicator (on the stream) has been set. Passing a NULL stream will produce the seg fault. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/ferror/

Comment: Shadyabhi: If `fopen` returns NULL, then the file isn't open; you're passing `NULL` in to `ferror`, which is invalid. You don't have an open file to pass in; that's what `NULL` means, that it couldn't give you a file pointer. `ferror` is for getting errors related to reading and writing the file, once it has actually been opened and you have the file to work with.

Comment: If the file couldn't be opened successfully, you don't have a valid `FILE *` value.  So, what will you call `ferror()` on?

Comment: @Brian
Thanx.. short and accurate:)

Comment: Slight complaint here, but why wouldn't you accept my answer? It was correct, timely and accurate, yet I have 1 vote. *sigh*

Comment: @Alastair I think the reason is that you didn't explain quite well enough why you need to check for `NULL` instead of using `ferror` to check for a file error. What you said is correct, and was timely, but it sounds like Shadyabhi is a real beginner here, and so needed things explained in a bit more detail (which is why I tried to explain in more detail in the comment on your answer, and then decided to expand that into a full answer). It's helpful, when explaining to beginners, to be as explicit as possible, and point out all of the alternatives to them.

Comment: @Brian Thank you for that response Brian. I appreciate the explanation as I certainly want to get better and helping. Thanks!